# Reliably overlay div (tooltip) above modal JQuery UI Dialog?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

I'm using CSS/Javascript to show tooltips for various inputs on mouseover. This works in a lot of various conditions but I'm having some trouble with inputs within a **modal** Jquery UI Dialog.
When I open the dialog the first time, it works 100% fine (tooltips show up in **front** of dialog), but if I close it and re-open it (**without** reloading the page), the tooltips will show up **behind** the dialog. I **did** explicitly set the **z-index** of tooltip div and dialog so that the tooltip has a higher value, but only works the first time .
If I set the dialog non-modal, everything is fine even when re-opening (but I highly prefer modal in this use case)
**Note**: Tested in Firefox 3.6.3

Any ideas on why it works only on first opening of dialog?

I have a helper div:

```
<div style="float: right; margin: 0px 10px 5px 0px;" id="tool_tip_help_id"></div>
```

In which I'll append the actual tooltip:

```
jq('div#tool_tip_help_id').append('<div id="tool_tip_id" class="toolTipDiv" style="display: none;"></div>');
```

CSS for tooltip div:

```
div.toolTipDiv{
    background-color:  #FFFF99;
    border-left: 1px solid gray;
    border-top: 1px solid gray;
    border-right: 3px solid gray;
    border-bottom: 3px solid gray; 
    position: absolute;
    padding: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
        line-height: 120%;
    font-size: 12px;
    z-index: 100; 
}
```

Relevant dialog declaration example:

```
jq("#Dialog").dialog( {
                bgiframe: true,
                autoOpen: false,
                width: 595,
                modal: true,
                draggable: false,
                zIndex: 1,
});
```

Comment: did you try to increase the z-index? Like 1001 or something

Comment: +1 - It does not work with 1001 but it works with 1003 :) (at least in Firefox, haven't tested yet in other browsers). I've just set it to be huge now (100100) to be sure.
If I check with Firebug, for some reason when the dialog is first opened, my dialog **zIndex** settings is *kinda* respected, it is set to **3**, but when I open it the 2nd time it is set to **1002**.

Comment: Not sure how to "close" this now, maybe you should add it as an answer :).
In any case this reminded me of not trusting 3rd party code to behave **exactly** as expected without actually checking. I usually know this, but overlooked it this time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not work with a z-index of 1001 but it works with 1003.

As such, setting it to a very large value should work (100100).

Comment: I added this as an answer so that it could be confirmed and closed.